# Is it possible to referencing the specific Xamarin.IOS into Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are trying to combine the Xamarin code that one is created using Xamarin Form (non XAML) and the other one is purely Xamarin.IOS.

We look at the library of Xamarin.Essential and it looks it doesn't have **CoreMotion.CMPedometer (iOS)** as we need to count the steps.

Is it possible to run the code within the Xamarin Form (shared) to handle specific OS?

Thanks

Comment: Not completely sure I understand what you want to achieve. But it sounds like this could be fixed with dependency injection. Define an interface in your forms project, register a specific implementation in your iOS project (and if you use other platforms make dummies there) and now you can get and use that implementation in the shared forms project. If it's something to do with visual elements take a look at custom renderers.

Comment: CoreMotion.CMPedometer class belongs to iOS implementation only which is a class to get the "steps" calculation. This is not a visual element obviously. Do you reckon it's possible then by dependency injection?

Comment: Well you're not giving a lot of information on what exactly you would like to do, but you could interface the entire `CoreMotion.CMPedometer` if needed, so yeah dependency injection is most likely able to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a **Dependency Service**.

All of the doco can be found here ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

An example is shown here in relation to device information (which has been cut down for simplicity reasons)

Firstly, you create an interface in your .NET standard/PCL project (if you're not using shared that is, which is likely the case).

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication.Interfaces
{
    public interface IDeviceInfo
    {
        String GetDeviceModel();
        String GetDeviceVersion();
    }
}
```

Then down in your platform specific project, create a Dependency Service that implements that interface and directs the compiler to recognise the class as a Dependency Service.

```
using System;
using MyApplication.Interfaces;
using UIKit;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyApplication.iOS.DeviceInfo))]
Namespace MyApplication.iOS
{
    public class DeviceInfo : IDeviceInfo
    {
        UIDevice _device;

        Public DeviceInfo()
        {
            _device = new UIDevice();
        }

        public string GetDeviceModel()
        {
            return _device.Model;
        }

        public string GetDeviceVersion()
        {
            return _device.SystemVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

Now from your .NET standard/PCL project, you can call the dependency service as required.

```
var deviceModel = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceInfo>().GetDeviceModel();
```

The above is specific for iOS which means you'd then need to implement the same concept for Android and UWP (or whatever is applicable).

See if that helps you.